# Website Showing Differently on Mobile?

Tags: android, html, css

My resume website appears great on Desktop. However, I discovered that my HTML paragraph tags don't scale properly when viewing it on different mobile web browsers (see attached image below).

[Screenshot 1: Website viewed using Facebook Messenger's built-in web browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOVWS.jpg)

[Screenshot 2: Website viewed using Android 7.0's Google Chrome App.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npIMf.jpg)

I use this CSS code for my HTML paragraph tags;

```
p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

My end goal is to make my website look like **screenshot 1** for all mobile web browsers. Can anyone help me identify the problem and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I have left out an important detail, my website's contents are all located within a table. It's formatted like this;

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="background">

<!-- all websites HTML here -->

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have also discovered that I can also use the following CSS and HTML to center my website (which might be better than putting all my content in a table);

```
#page-wrap {
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <!-- all websites HTML here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">` ?

Comment: Where do you set your font size for your paragraphs?

Comment: I didn't set a font size for my paragraph. Should I be using font-size: 1em;?

Comment: I recommend using a more responsive design. Screenshot 1 is a pretty poor experience on mobile. Also `font-size: 1em` wouldn't do anything. `em`s are a relative unit, 1 essentially meaning 100% of current size.

Comment: @Sean_Codes, I have tried adding the meta name and unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Styles */
}


/* Tablet (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
}


/* Tablet (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* Styles */
}


/* Tablet (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37em) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however the results are still the same. :(